# Returning entries from json only with certain flag

Tags: javascript, json

i'm trying to grab my results from json. say i have a 20 fruit types, but only 3 of the fruit types have `price=free` in the result. how can I return the price=free results only?

here's what im doing to return the results..

```
fruits.payload.entries[count].name
```

I want to get the name of the fruits that have `price=free`

Comment: Could you post a code example of the JSON response you are getting?

Comment: Sure        for (;;);{"__sa":1,"payload":{"entries":[{"name":apple,"price":"free","text":"Apple","path":"apple.php","photo":"","other":"","da":"1","id":9}

Answer (score 0):

```
$(results).filter(function(){
   return this.price == "free"
});
```

Comment: yes. Sorry thought you were using it. If not you can loop over the result set using array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try json:select() — "CSS-like selectors for JSON" http://jsonselect.org/

Answer (score 0):

If the service your talking to doesn't support that query then you will have to filter them your self.

For completeness here is the none framework style loop:

```
var i, len, a, freeOnly = [], item;
a = fruits.payload.entries;

for( i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i ++){
     item = a[i];
     if( item.price === 'free' ){
         freeOnly.push(item);
     }
}
```

For free item names you would do:

```
function freeItemNames(items){
    var i, len, freeNames = [], item;


    for( i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i ++){
         item = items[i];
         if( item.price === 'free' ){
             freeNames.push(item.name);
         }
    } 
    return freeNames;
}

// call like this
freeItemNames(fruits.payload.entries);

// should output something like
["Free fruit 1","Fruity two"]
```

Comment: Thanks! So how do I return the name for those with item.price = free?

Comment: sorry,  just added another more complete example of a function extracting the name attribute